# HP ML350p Gen8 won't boot from PCIe SSD

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, pci-express

I have a HP ML350p Gen8 with a PCIe SSD and I'm trying to boot from it, but it won't do it. I can see the PCIe SSD in the list of hard drives when to choose where to install windows 10 pro, but after I install windows, it would give an error about missing some files. I tried it on a couple occasions with different BIOS settings, but no luck. Did anyone install windows on a PCIe SSD on a ML350p? Thank you

Comment: How about telling us what type of PCIe SSD you're using... More details are better.

Comment: Some basic information like what the error message is might help too.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 isn't supported on the ML350P Gen 8.  There's a support matrix over here: http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/windows.aspx

You might want to look at the HP Z series which have Xeon processors but support the OS you are trying to use.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have the same hardware, but it sound's like a broken Windows installation. I had this once, but the image on my installation device (USB-Stick) itself was brocken and it was not able to complete the Windows installation.